# how to show alert messege when date range overlaps existing date ranges in angularjs

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs

i am working on a project where i have few existing dates
suppose Existing from dates and to dates are shown below

- Existing From Date  and to dates
- 27/11/2020 to 02/12/2020
- 01/01/2021 to 15/01/2021

and now if i am trying to enter a record with

- 24/11/2020 to 29/11/2020 or 29/11/2020 to 07/12/2020

i want to show alert date ranges should not overlap

i am not able to create logic which can fullfill all conditions

so basically

if there is an existing date range 5-10

Then 1-5 or 1-6 or 6-7 or 8-10 or 10-20 should not be allowed

here is my code i have written following lines where i am looing through existing records and comparing newly entering dates with existing records

```
angular.forEach($scope.Selling, function (index, value) {
                if ((NewFromDate <= new Date(index.ExistingPackagePriceToDate) && NewToDate >= new Date(index.ExistingFromDate))) {
                    alert("dates should not overlap");
                }
});
```

can anybody help me with this to build the logic

if it is in jquery still i can convert that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is actually an interesting one. You need to figure out your cases of overlap

1. NewFromDate <= ExistingFromDate And NewToDate >= ExistingFromDate
   Visually

```
     |       |  -- Existing
|       | -- New
```

Or

```
     |       | -- Existing
|                 | -- New
```

2. NewFromDate >= ExistingFromDate And NewFromDate <= ExistingPackagePriceToDate

```
     |       | -- Existing
       |   | -- New
```

Or

```
     |       | -- Existing
       |       | -- New
```

So your code would have to become something like this:

```
angular.forEach($scope.Selling, function (index, value) {
      Console.log(NewFromDate.toString() + '-' + NewToDate.toString());
      Console.log(index.ExistingFromDate + '-' + index.ExistingPackagePriceToDate);
      if ((NewFromDate <= new Date(index.ExistingFromDate) && NewToDate >= new Date(index.ExistingFromDate))) {
            alert("dates should not overlap");
      }
      if ((NewFromDate >= new Date(index.ExistingFromDate) && NewFromDate <= new Date(index.ExistingPackagePriceToDate))) {
            alert("dates should not overlap");
      }
});
```

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific than that. Tell me the date values that are not working for you. You can log them in the console like in the updated answer.

Comment: if there is an existing date range 5-10

Then 1-5 or 1-6 or 6-7 or 8-10 or 10-20 should not be allowed i want this logic but if date range is from 1-3 or 11-15 it should not show any error

Comment: This is achieved by the code above. What's the specific case that makes you think it doesn't.

Comment: Check your console for the dates as shown in the example.